# How does this primary key fetch all the users in the group?

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, database, nosql

I'm trying to understand data modeling in Cassandra coming from a relational background using [this](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling) article.However, I fail to understand one of the examples.

In **Example 2 User Groups**:

```
CREATE TABLE groups (
    groupname text,
    username text,
    email text,
    age int,
    PRIMARY KEY (groupname, username)
)
```

> Note that the PRIMARY KEY has two components: groupname, which is the
>   partitioning key, and username, which is called the clustering key.
>   This will give us one partition per groupname. Within a particular
>   partition (group), rows will be ordered by username. **Fetching a group
>   is as simple as doing the following**:

```
SELECT * FROM groups WHERE groupname = ?
```

However, what I fail to understand is, if we were to create a group, we'd be be passing a single group name and  corresponding user name in the insert.

So, how would it be possible to retrieve **all** the users belonging to a single group using the select statement? Also, since the groupname is the primary key, we can't add more users with the same groupname as it would lead to a violation.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of a partition as a data bucket.  It can hold a single row or multiple rows of data.  When you read that data bucket, Cassandra can very efficiently access all the rows within the bucket, or just a range of rows you specify by the clustering key.

A partition is the unit of replication within Cassandra, so all the data within one partition bucket is stored on a single node (with possibly extra copies on other nodes if you use a higher replication factor than one).

But the partition key is only part of the key.  Each row in the bucket still needs to have a unique primary key, so in that example, each user you stored in a particular group partition would need to have a different user name.  So it is the combination of groupname and username that needs to be unique.  You can always insert more users under the same groupname as long as each username within the group is different.  If you inserted with a duplicate username, then it would be an update to the row with that username instead of adding a row.

Comment: Thanks for the comment..So would I have access to the other attributes of user such as email, age etc... If yes, how would I go about updating the age of a user in a group?

Comment: Would it be along the lines of fetching the users in the group and  firing a subsequent query to update the user information in a different table..?

Comment: You would update the individual row for the user you wanted to change.  For example in CQL you would do this, "UPDATE groups SET age=30 WHERE groupname='somegroup' AND username='someuser';"